# Several REST endpoint on WSO2 ESB proxy service

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm new in this technology, so please excuse me for the question.
I have a WSO2 ESB configured on server. I managed to configure different Proxy Services one by one, the thing i'd like to do, since they are all child of one service to put them into one proxy and use it with parameters.
Something like:

```
http://localhost:8290/services/URL1/{id}
http://localhost:8290/services/URL2/{id}
```

I can't find comprehensive explanation on how to do this.
Could someone provide me with the proxy source example with more then one endpoint defined there, if it is possible.
Thanks a lot in advance,
Liudmila

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST apis , there you can use url mapping and url templates  as you want.
check the document[1]

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Getting+Started+with+REST+APIs#GettingStartedwithRESTAPIs-URLmappings

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i created as many proxy services as i need. So far it works!